# What's the startup/reboot time for iPad (3rd generation) compared to other iOS devices?

Tags: startup, ipad

I'd like to know, in people's personal experience so far, about how long the new iPad takes to start up (in seconds), especially when compared with other devices running iOS.

For the purposes of uniformity, I'll define "startup time" as the time between the depression of the lock switch and the moment the lock screen appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS device boot times (timed using a second hand):

```
iPad   (3rd gen.)   iOS5    32 seconds
iPad 2 (2nd gen.)           No Results
iPad   (1st gen.)   iOS5    50 seconds

iPhone 4S           iOS5    42 seconds
iPhone 4            iOS5    49 seconds
iPhone 4 (GSM)      iOS5    46 seconds
iPhone 3GS          iOS5    85 seconds
iPhone 3G           iOS4.3  87 seconds
iPhone (2G)                 No Results

iPod touch 4G               No Results
iPod touch 3G               No Results
iPod touch 2G               No Results
iPod touch 1G               No Results
```

Feel free to edit this answer and add your own times.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on what apps are running, and what's installed on the device?

Comment: @Moshe I don't think so, unless it's jailbroken, but maybe someone else knows? Might be a good question to ask.

Comment: [Done](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44656/is-the-boot-time-of-an-ios-device-affected-by-the-apps-that-are-running-at-shutd)

Comment: A note: since pressing the wake button and releasing it can introduce a time delay on the order of one or two seconds, it's best to time a start from plugging into power to kick the boot time in a more reproducible manner.

Comment: @bmike What does plugging it in have to do with it?